# Link to local folder in mobile application

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, local, target

I have a question. 
Is it possible to link from START.HTML.

to specified folders

/Aanpas project/assets/www/View/no_records.html (Woman section)

/Aanpas project/assets/www/View men/no_records.html (Men section)

My project folder is structured like :

> +SCR - Main activity
>
> +Gen
>
> -Assets
>
> -WWW
>
> --**View**
>
> ---About html
>
> ---Birth control_single.html
>
> ---No_records.html
>
> ---start.html
>
> **--View men**
>
> ---About html
>
> ---Birth control_single.html
>
> ---No_records.html

---

I have tried it with the following code but it didn't work.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function newDoc() {
    window.location.assign("../Aanpas project/assets/www/View/no_records.html")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Load" onclick="newDoc()">

</body>
</html>
```

Pictures of Idea and Project structure

[Link to project stucture](http://i58.tinypic.com/j14sw5.png)

[Link to idea of application](http://i58.tinypic.com/27wtw8h.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You're allready in the right folder, have you tried to do this?

```
function newDoc() {
     window.location.assign("no_records.html")
 }
```